# Is there any point to sleep more than an hour?

Tags: fallout-4

Other than to pass time?

I mean does it increase the time Well Rested/Lover's Embrace will stay active?

I know it doesn't restore more health, as sleeping a single hour appears to restore 100% of lost health, and it doesn't appear to have any other benefit, does it?

Comment: Yes, of course. If you are only getting one hour of sleep a night, you'll be tired, unhealthy and grumpy-- oh wait, this is arqade. Haha, Nevermind, carry on.

Comment: Games are getting horrifyingly close to reality these days ...

Comment: @GeoHam that's what happening in FO4 on survival mode..and because there is no other way to save but to sleep it becomestedious

Answer (score 16, accepted):

As you say in the question, there is no additional benefit to sleeping more, other than passing additional time.

There's no length increase to buffs, for example Well Rested (which lasts [12 hours](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/Well_Rested) from awakening regardless of time-slept).

Comment: Source quotation: "The bonus lasts for twelve hours from the time of waking up, regardless of length of sleep. Sleeping in any bed will cancel the effect. But if it is an owned bed, it will return immediately. "

Comment: @DCShannon: (Though the owned bed part is irrelevant in FO4)

Comment: @DCShannon - It seems you can only get the 'well-rested' bonus from sleeping in settlements or rented/owned rooms (such as the bar/hotel in Diamond City). Sleeping in a random sleeping bag/matress in the wild will not award the perk

Comment: @Robotnik You can get the Lover's embrace perk from any sleeping bag or mattress that lies around anywhere in the wild though. Trust me, Cait and I take a lot of "naps" in between exterminating raiders and super mutants and the perk notification always pops up.

Comment: @DCShannon - I have tested Well Rested as I said, not lovers embrace.

Comment: @Robotnik I'm sorry, I didn't equate "it seems" with "I have tested". In that case, the "owned bed part" is not irrelevant in FO4.

Comment: it only a couple of hours if on Survival (in-game hours) and need sleep at least 5 hours to get well-rested (more, up to 9 if character got health issues)

Answer (score 9):

It is used for role-playing.

If your character has the "Night Person" perk, then he will mostly be a night person, so he will be sleeping by day (or the other way around if having the "Solar Powered" perk.)

Comment: "Other than to pass time"